# Using jQuery to Style iFrame

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I've read about a dozen similar questions on here and tried everything I can think of, but I'm obviously doing something wrong because I just can't get it to work.

**HTML**:

```
<iframe name="posts" id="posts" src="edit.php">
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe#posts').ready(function() {
        var frame = $('iframe#posts').contentDocument;
        console.log($('#adminmenu', frame));
        $('#adminmenu', frame).css('display', 'none !important');
    });
});
```

The console is outputting:

```
[<ul id=​"adminmenu" style=​"display:​ none !important;​ ">​…​</ul>​]
```

which is the correct element. However the `display:none` is never being applied in the browser. Also, I find it odd that the console is outputting with the inline style even though it's being set after the `console.log()` statement (not sure if that's related or not, but doesn't seem like it should be).

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working?

I should also add that there is a `<ul id="adminmenu">` in the main document body as well, but I figured by providing the iframe context it should be targeting the iframe.

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to use `!important` in the css property

Comment: Maybe this is a timing issue? Maybe the inlying iframe hasn't loaded yet? You could try out by adding an alert()

Comment: Ya, I tried without the !important but it wasn't working either, so I figured I'd brute force it.

Comment: Re. timing - that's why I wrapped it in a `$('iframe#posts').ready()`. Maybe this doesn't do what I think it should?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried using jQuery's `contents()` function instead of `contentDocument`?

```
$("iframe#posts").contents().find("#adminmenu").hide();
```

Updated: changed `.css("display", "none !important")` to simply `.hide()`.

Comment: I could've sworn I tried this and it wasn't working... but now it is :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For an iframe, try the 'load' method instead of 'ready'.  Also, use 'contents()' instead of 'contentDocument' to get the content of the iframe.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe#posts').load(function() {
        var frame = $('iframe#posts').contents();
        /* other code */
    });
});
```

Comment: I started going down this route when things were looking dim, but I ran into another issue. The links in the "iframe" now load full-browser, but I want them to remain "framed" as well. Any suggestions on that? I even started hijacking the links to make them open in the "frame", but with click events and other unknowns it seems nearly impossible.