# How can I set :hover to false for elements in an iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, hover, tumblr

What I am trying to do is set the hover effect on the tumblr follow and dashboard button on the themes I make to false.

If you don't know, they have some sort of `iframe` with the id `#tumblr_controls` that they have automatically on your page with their own properties.

How would I be able to turn off the individual hover effects of those links in the `iframe` while preserving the click abilities and all?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow , please try to include your code .. other wise no body can help .. we are not mind readers , and we wont write you your code .. please edit it to get the desired response :)

Comment: there isn't code and that's the main issue for me. It comes with it and is not directly in the source code, which is why I can't simply just disable the hover effect. The question is if you have an iframe, can you disable hover effects on the elements in that iframe

Comment: then please visit  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449477/using-jquery-to-style-iframe

Comment: well then where are you going to see the iframe? whats that url?

Comment: it's alright, I took a different method and just figured out the hover effect used rather than just not having one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change CSS (or JS) within an `iframe` from a different domain unfortunately. What you see is what you get. It was likely done like this for security reasons, for example Twitter doesn't want your site injecting dodgy code into their tweet `iframe` as it would reflect wrongly on them.

See this for more details ['Can I apply CSS to the elements within an iframe?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286196/1156119)